# multiple array combine into other array with key using php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

We have three array something like this but these are dynamic

```
Array
(
    [04/07/2013] => 2
    [05/02/2013] => 1
    [06/02/2013] => 1
    [08/07/2013] => 2
    [08/08/2013] => 3
    [09/07/2013] => 2
    [11/07/2013] => 1
    [16/03/2013] => 1
    [17/07/2013] => 1
    [18/04/2013] => 2
    [18/07/2013] => 1
    [21/05/2013] => 2
    [24/05/2013] => 8
    [25/04/2013] => 2
    [26/04/2013] => 1
    [26/06/2013] => 1
    [30/05/2013] => 1
)
Array
(
    [01/08/2013] => 42
    [02/08/2013] => 2
    [03/08/2013] => 3
    [07/08/2013] => 29
    [09/08/2013] => 4
    [10/08/2013] => 4
    [11/08/2013] => 31
    [19/07/2013] => 4
    [20/07/2013] => 4
    [22/07/2013] => 13
    [23/07/2013] => 69
    [29/07/2013] => 4
    [31/07/2013] => 5
)
Array
(
    [13/02/2013] => 2
    [26/04/2013] => 2
    [04/06/2013] => 2
    [20/06/2013] => 2
    [04/07/2013] => 2
    [09/07/2013] => 1
    [01/08/2013] => 1
    [07/08/2013] => 1
    [08/08/2013] => 3
)
```

We want to combine into other array with keys(key must be remain same).If all three array keys has same put it into the same key other wise create a key for and put it value if array has key other wise put it with zero value.

Here we tried for this

```
$maximum = max($countVisi,$countClic,$countClai);
    if($countClic==$maximum){
        $maxim = $clickArray;
    }elseif($countVisi>=$maximum){
        $maxim = $visitArray;
    }elseif($countClai>=$maximum){
        $maxim = $claimsArray;
    }else{
        $maxim = $visitArray;
    }
```

we count the maximum index array and foreach the loop like this

```
foreach($maxim as $key=>$values){
        if($visitArray[$key]){
            $vv[$key] = $visitArray[$key];
        }else{
            $vv[$key] = 0;
        }
        if($clickArray[$key]){
            $cc[$key] = $clickArray[$key];
        }else{
            $cc[$key] = 0;
        }
        if($claimsArray[$key]){
            $kk[$key] = $claimsArray[$key];
        }else{
            $kk[$key] = 0;
        }
        $combineArrayNext[$key][] = $vv[$key];
        $combineArrayNext[$key][] = $cc[$key];
        $combineArrayNext[$key][] = $kk[$key];
        //$vvvvv = explode('/' , $key);
        //$myKey[$key] = "'".date('d M Y' , strtotime($vvvvv[2]."/".$vvvvv[1]."/".$vvvvv[0]))."'";
    }
```

The problem is that we are getting only according to max array key.It leave the key which are not exits in max array.

Sorry for the less explaining , I think you understand my problem.Please share some idea with us to solve my problem.

Thanks

Comment: For better understanding print what the result array should look like.

Comment: I didn't understand your explanation. Your code uses 6 arrays, and you're only showing 3. And you didn't give an example of the result like u_mulder requested. How do you expect anyone to help?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code helps you:

```
$dates = array_merge(array_keys($arr1), array_keys($arr2), array_keys($arr3));
foreach($dates as $date) {
  $new_arr[$date] = array('click' => isset($arr1[$date])? $arr1[$date] : 0,
                          'visit' => isset($arr2[$date])? $arr2[$date] : 0,
                          'claim' => isset($arr3[$date])? $arr3[$date] : 0 );
}
```